# Vulnerability risk in modern vlans

Tags: networking, security, hacking

I'm looking at using VLAN to separate some traffic without buying a bunch of switches for two or three devices. The plan is to use untagged ports for dedicated lans with an external router connecting any networks that need connecting.

Are VLAN still as vulnerable to hacking as they were suppose to be back 5 years ago? Most of the articles I find in searching are 5+ years old. So I don't know if people gave up on vlans and just use physical switches or if modern switches have more or less fixed the problems.

Comment: Exactly what vulnerabilities are you referring to? Virtually everyone uses VLANs and they're reasonably secure. That's part of the whole point, after all. So you need to be very specific about what you're talking about.

Comment: I was referring to vlan hopping, mac spoofing, etc. It was a generalized question. I've just seen articles talking about different vulnerabilities in the VLAN implementations, but those articles are 5+ years old.

Comment: VLAN hopping (by switch spoofing or double tagging) can easily be migitated (e.g. just don't allow trunking on client ports and don't use native VLANs for clients, both are standard approaches anyways), MAC spoofing is no vulnerability that is specific to VLAN and can be migitated with encryption. VLAN is an industry standard and the vulnerabilities you describe are not caused by implementing VLAN but by implementing VLAN wrong. It's like asking  "Are LAN still as vulnerable to hacking as ...?" LAN and VLAN are the roads, what car you use and if you put on the seatbelt is your responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

VLANs themselves aren't vulnerable to hacking at all. It's the switches - or rather their configuration - that may be vulnerable.

Access ports (the ports connected to hosts) need to be secured.

- Using tagged VLANs on an access port allows VLAN hopping.
- Leaving dynamic VLAN protocols like MVRP or GVRP open on access ports allows a client with appropriate software to join a VLAN.
- Leaving switches with VLAN trunks in physically unprotected places can compromise the trunked VLANs.

VLANs require careful planning and configuration. Then they can be an important part of your security architecture.